# Why a simple textblock app runs and a simple app with a button fails in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, silverlight-4.0, wpf-controls

Folks, I am seeing that the below code gives runtime error when I paste it in notepad and save as test.xaml and run it.

```
<Page xmlns = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <TextBlock Text="Hi Ramakrishnan, good morning"/>
    <Button x:Name=”blueButton”
        Width=”100”
        Height=”40”
        Background=”Blue”
        Content=”Click Me” />
</Page>
```

But the below code doesn't give any error but displays the textblock content very correctly in the browser. Any thoughts ? I have also checked including a textbox in place of button above, still same error.

```
<Page xmlns = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <TextBlock Text="Hi Ramakrishnan, good morning"/>
</Page>
```

Comment: Can you post the runtime error?

Comment: Probably you are using another " symbols. Try to replace them in Button with those from TextBlock...

Comment: @DanPuzey: Buddy its very simple, just paste in notepad and save as .xaml and double click. Again edit it to remove button and save and run and see the difference :) Anyway the runtime error is below: An error occurred in the application you were using
You can try the following:
Restart the application. 
Click the "More Information" link below for details about this error. 
 More Information 
Startup URI: C:\Users\Ramakrishnan\Desktop\test.xaml
Application Identity:

Comment: @JleruOHeP: Buddy, just remove button and try with textbox if you suspect button. <Page xmlns = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
<TextBlock Text="Hi Ramakrishnan, good morning"/>
<TextBox Text="Hello..."/>
</Page>

Comment: The error is "System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException: Invalid character in the given encoding. Line 4, position 20."  It's definitely a bad quote-character error.

Comment: @Divine: "Buddy," why would I go to that effort to answer your question?  If you want help, put some effort in.  People are suggesting solutions and you are telling them to try it for you - and yet it's likely that you've NOT pasted the exact code you have in your file, and you've not provided a full error message.

Comment: @Divine: When debugging your application, you should click on the "More Information" link and it will show you the full exception and stack trace.  The information you listed in your comment is a generic message you get when an application fails to load in IE.

Comment: @JonSenchyna: Thank you, perfect, actually I didn't know that earlier :( I am new, I am really new to programming. thank you so much, your info helps me greatly :) Cheers :)

Comment: @DanPuzey: Uhmm No :( I copied the info and tried pasting here, but it went to "negative" character limit when I pasted that whole info :( I couldn't paste it. Thats why I told like that :( Apologize.... Please understand... :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to wrap your TextBlock/Button in a StackPanel or other control that allows multiple controls in it's content.

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBlock Text="Hi Ramakrishnan, good morning"/>
        <Button x:Name="blueButton"
        Width="100"
        Height="40"
        Background="Blue"
        Content="Click Me" />
    </StackPanel>
```

Comment: Heh, I was focussing so much on the smart quotes I didn't even notice that :-)

Comment: Hey Mark !!!!!!! You are absolutely right :) Thank you so so so much :) Beautiful :) yayy.... :) I appreciate your helping nature.... Cheers buddy :)

Answer (score 1):

Your pasted code is using "smart quotes" instead of "normal quotes" on the button.

```
<TextBlock Text="Hi Ramakrishnan, good morning"/>  <-- normal quotes
<Button x:Name=”blueButton”                        <-- smart quotes
```

Have you edited or saved or pasted this through MSWord, perhaps?

(If this isn't the problem then it's possible that what you've pasted in your question isn't exactly what you have in your Xaml file, in which case you should update your question...)

Comment: Hi Dan, thank you so much for investigating/helping. Thats a good point while investigating too. Thank you so much again :) Cheers buddy....